# Python requests to login https

Tags: html, python-3.x

tried the whole afternoon to google, but did not really find a working solution, maybe just little thing, i feel I am quite close.

I try to login a website then download some files, but stuck at login page.

```
import requests
import getpass
import shutil
##import json
##import sha3
##import hashlib

site_url= 'https://www.marketing.org.nz/Login'
file_url = 'https://www.marketing.org.nz/Folder?Action=Download&Folder_id=67&File=NZDI.zip'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',}
login_info = {'User_name':'xxxx',
             'User_password':'xxxx',
              'User_Cookie':'false'}

s = requests.Session()
s.get(site_url)
r = s.post(site_url,
           data=login_info,
           headers=headers,
           verify=True
           )
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

It return the following results (500 as status_code and following html). Thanks very much for anyone can help me on this. I have limited knowledge of html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- frame.jsp -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '1762792827285594');
    fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1762792827285594&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

  <script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-22187118-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>


  <link href="/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="/public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="/public/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/public/img/favicon.png" />
  <script src="/public/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/yku4xru.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>
  <title>Marketing Association</title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cyberglue(R) ver: 17.10.0 Copyright 1998-2018 Cyberglue Software Limited, Auckland, New Zealand. sn : 12232"/>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>



    <!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){
    z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
    d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
    _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
    $.src='//v2.zopim.com/?3LnjHu3AVCkYD9pgOKw7tOeA3o1sTtFS';z.t=+new Date;$.
    type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');
    </script>
    <!--End of Zopim Live Chat Script-->



  <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
  var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  a.src=document.location.protocol+"//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0032/7564.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
  a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
  </script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/2094870490.js"></script>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-W795CJJ');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
  <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-W795CJJ"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->





<!-- structure.jsp -->













      <!-- ecs/ecs.jsp -->



<section class="intro ecs">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">


        <div class="static-modal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Internal Server Error</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><input id="ps296994285" value="Login" name="Action" type="hidden"/><input id="c1243544753" value="" name="Confirm" type="hidden"/><div class="col-md-12"><fieldset><legend></legend><a id=""></a></fieldset><div class="form-group viewer"><div class="col-sm-12"><span style="" class="form-control-static">Unknown action for POST request: </span></div></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><div><span onclick="parent.history.back();"><a class="btn btn-default btn btn-default"><i class='fa fa-arrow-left'></i>&nbsp;Go Back</a></span> <a href="/" rel="nofollow" class="btn btn-default btn-default"><i class='fa fa-home'></i>  Go to Home Page</a> </div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></div></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>









  <script src="/public/js/all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/public/js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1011888936;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1011888936/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>


  <!--Additional Google Analytics script added for Ubiquity - see /helpdesk/tickets/52843 -->  
  <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 987396266;
var google_conversion_label = "Iz3-CJjOpmoQqvHp1gM";
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function escapeHtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace("%26%2339%3B", "%27");
}
 </script> 
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/987396266/?value=1.00&amp;currency_code=NZD&amp;label=Iz3-CJjOpmoQqvHp1gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript> 

<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/3866588.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->

<!-- Start of LinkedIn Insight Tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
_linkedin_data_partner_id = "89694";
</script><script type="text/javascript">
(function(){var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})();
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=89694&fmt=gif" />
</noscript>
<!-- End of LinkedIn Insight Tag -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the response from the login host ?

Comment: It return 500 as the status

Comment: Can i look the response ?

Comment: @HuntsMan, thanks for your help. I have edited my post to includes the results

Comment: @HuntsMan thanks for your help, and I have solved the issue by editing the login_info